# Why do most ulimit recommendations call for setting file descriptor limits to 65535?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, performance-tuning

In searching for max file descriptor `ulimit` tuning recommendations, many sites recommend setting a file descriptor size of 65535.  In some cases, its 100000, 120000, and even higher.  Some of these posts date back 20 years ago.

For some posts, I'm sure it's an arbitrary value.  But it seems that there are so many recommendations for these values, and 65535 in particular.  Why do so many blog posts and server tuning docs suggest setting max file descriptors to something like 65535?  On the surface it seems like an arbitrary value.  Is it for historical reasons?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447583/ulimit-vs-file-max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly arbitrary. Someone picked a value for a recommendation, and many others copied it.

Defaults in the single-digit thousand range might be too small for a few hundred database files, or a few thousand mail spools. So 5 or 6 decimal digits may be an appropriate order of magnitude.

65535 happens to be 64k, also known as the largest 16 bit number.  And then there is the stranger number you might see of 64000, perhaps someone mixed binary and decimal thinking. That's quite a lot of open files, but does not reflect the maximum possible value on a modern system.

"Modern" systems qualifier, because if you go far back enough 64k was a limit on some platforms. Obsolete HP-UX function call [pstat_getfile() broke above 64k](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man5/maxfiles_lim.5.html). Obviously not relevant to Linux, but if there is no need to go higher, why not keep it below a familiar 64k number?